# Setting Kubernetes DNS cluster addon for high availability

Tags: kubernetes

We're using Kubernetes 1.3.6 on AWS
Currently we have a single DNS pod of the cluster addon on the system namespace.
If the node which the pod runs on fails for some reason the cluster's DNS service is shut down and most of it can't work correctly.

My question is: How can I setup a more robust DNS service? Can I just kubectl scale the replication controller for more pods? Will that work?

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/33239 will be in soon(-ish) which should let you do that.

Comment: @AnirudhRamanathan The PR is for auto-scaling the DNS.
What will happen today if I scale the replication controller for more than one pod?

Answer (score 1):

You can just scale up the DNS addon manually (or alter the ReplicationController's `spec.replicas`, depending on how you deploy).

The DNS addon uses basic Kubernetes objects for availability like any application you might deploy. It is behind a Service (called `kube-dns` by default) that has `spec.clusterIP` assigned to the same IP address the `kubelet` is aware of (via the `--cluster-dns` flag). The Service is the consistent access point for cluster DNS and will load balance the requests across however many kube-dns Pods you have.

Comment: I wonder why was it set for a single pod by default in the first place. Such a critical single point of failure...

Comment: From my experience, it is always scheduled to another node in case of node failure. This happens in just few seconds.

Comment: The main methods of deploying Kubernetes include a means to increase the number of kube-dns replicas at cluster creation. `kube-up.sh`, for example, generally uses an env var `DNS_REPLICAS` to override the default of 1 ([one example](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/41b5fe86b61323779fd73738eab321697ca47105/cluster/aws/config-default.sh#L123)). I think the default of 1 replica for these installers is a decision to make a 'kick the tires' cluster work with minimal resources, while the expectation is that users moving to more serious use cases will customize the setting.